# change registrationcontroller create action failure redirect path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to implement a signup form on the homepage of my app. The successful flow (registering) works perfectly. The problem lies in when a validation fails, namely triggering a rerender of the devise registration :new action. I would like this rerender to happen on the homepage instead of devises own view.

I've tried to rewrite the devise controller by adding the root_path location to the "respond_with location" as seen below, however for some reason this continues to trigger a render of the devise views.

```
  # POST /resource
  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource.persisted?
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_up
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message! :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      set_minimum_password_length

      respond_with resource, location: root_path # HERE!!!
    end
  end
```

I'm wondering what a clean way would be to fix this problem

**EDIT**

It just struck me that I could render the home layout with the preferred template, however this feels a bit improper.

```
  # POST /resource
  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource.persisted?
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_up
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message! :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      set_minimum_password_length

      render layout: 'frontend/home', template: 'frontend/home/index'
    end
  end
```

Comment: You don't want to redirect when validation fails as all the user input will be lost. So you're on the right track.

Comment: But rendering a seperate "new" view on validation failure may give a better ux unless the registration form is at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually went with the approach as appended with the edit above:

```
  render layout: 'frontend/home', template: 'frontend/home/index'
```